# Conflicting NodeJS Versions

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

I've used NVM to install NodeJS on my Amazon Linux AMI instance, but have the following issue:

When typing `node -v` it displays `v7.10.0`, but if I do `console.log(process.version);` it displays `v0.10.46`.

The commands I used to install NVM were:

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh | bash
nvm install node`

Does anybody have any tips on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is it possible that somehow you installed node using yum? Can you try `which node`?

Comment: `which node` returns the following `~/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/bin/node`

Comment: I have a suspicion that you have multiple versions of node installed. Can you try `yum list installed` and see if there is node in the list?

Comment: Actually, a colleague of mine just pointed out that `node -v` and `sudo node -v` respond with different versions (v7.10.0 and v0.10.46 respectively)... So it looks like need to get the sudo user to use v7.10.0...

Comment: It does mean that you have multiple node versions installed.

Comment: @Ilia Frenkel: The output of `yum list installed` shows `nodejs.x86_64 0.10.46-1.e16` installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why I was getting 2 different versions was because NVM installs nodejs for the current user, however I was using `sudo node index.js` (root user) to run my script.

Don't run your node script in a production environment using `sudo`. Be sure to use the current user.

If your script only runs using `sudo` (In my case it was an ExpressJS app running on port 8080) investigate why that is the case and resolve *that* issue rather than trying to install nodejs for the root user.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple versions of node installed. Remove the one that you don't need (I assume it is the 0.10.46 one).

Comment: So I just ran `sudo yum remove nodejs` which removed node from `yum list installed`. But now doing `sudo node -v` responds with `sudo: node: command not found`. I'm looking into a solution.

Comment: Can you run `node -v` without sudo?

Comment: Yes I can, sorry for not adding that info. I'm looking into how to get NVM to apply to the sudo user